# Propel/symfony: problem with a criteria

Tags: symfony1, criteria, propel

I have this query inside a method:

```
public static function pincopalla(){

     $con = Propel::getConnection(SediI18nPeer::DATABASE_NAME);

     $sql = "select * from sedii18n where culture = :country
     UNION
     select * from sedii18n where culture <> :country";


     $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);

    $result = $stmt->execute(array(':country' => 'eu'));

    return $result;
```

}

When i call the method i get the symfony error below tough cashgold_new.sedii18n exists..:

```
500 | Internal Server Error | PDOException
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cashgold_new.sedii18n'    doesn't exist
stack trace

* at ()
  in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/DebugPDOStatement.php line 99 ...
          96.     public function execute($input_parameters = null)
          97.     {
          98.         $debug    = $this->pdo->getDebugSnapshot();
          99.         $return    = parent::execute($input_parameters);
         100.         
         101.         $sql = $this->getExecutedQueryString();
         102.         $this->pdo->log($sql, null, __METHOD__, $debug);
```

To debug it i have changed the class name of the argument of getConnection(), expecting the same error, but...the error is not the same!..:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'SediBlaBlaI18nPeer' not found in
>   /home/javier/Aptana_Studio_Workspace/cashgold/lib/model/SediI18nPeer.php
>   on line 25

Any idea whats the problem?

Javi

Answer (score 0):

Following the error message **Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cashgold_new.sedii18n'**

Check that you have a DB/schema called `cashgold_new` containing a table `sedii18n`

BTW your query is very strange.
Isn't it equivalent to `select * from sedii18n` ?